# Magento 2 sort by position in custom module is not working properly

Tags: magento2, module, sorting

I want to sort images by position, and I am using this code

```
public function getCollection() {
   $collection = $this->_mymoduleFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('status', 1)->setOrder('position', 'ASC');
   return $collection;
}
```

it is working perfectly fine from 0-9. when i give position as 10 it is showing after 1 like 0,1,10,2 etc.
How could I sort correctly like 0,1,2,3...,10,11 etc?
Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

This issue probably caused by you set `position` column in DB to `varchar`. Update it to `int` and try again.